# Bootstrap h-100 only on medium screen and up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4. Is it possible to have a `div` be `h-100` on a medium screen and up, but on small and below just adjust to its content?

I have the following `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-12 h-100 p-3" style="overflow:auto;">
```

When the screen is `sm` or smaller, I want the `div` to not be `h-100` and adjust to its content like a `dic` normally would.

On a side note, the Bootstrap `overflow-auto` class didn't seem to work, hence the inline style.

Comment: please mark the answer accepted so others know the question is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to add CSS for that. I'd recommend adding a new `h-md-100` class like...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .h-md-100 {
        height: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/a74gDaElDR)

Comment: I was hoping I did not have to add any custom classes. But this works. Thanks!